# ошибки при компиляции Windows Forms приложения

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Почему при при запуске отладки у меня появились ошибки LNK 2028,LNK 2019 и LNK 1120.Я уверен,что дело в возвращаемом значении после else,но как это объяснить
это код файла cat.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "cat.h"
long double cat(int N, int term, int sum)
{
    if (N < 0)
        return 0;
    if (N == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        for (int start = 1; start <= N; start++) {
            int product = 1;
            for (int j = start; j <= 2 * start; j++)
                product *= j;
            sum += product;
        }
        return sum;




}
```

это фрагмент кода заголовочного файла сat.h:

```
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        int number = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
        int factor = cat(number);
        textBox2->Text = System::Convert::ToString(factor);
    }
```

Comment: я думаю ошибка вообще не из-за этого. На с++ мало кодил. Вроде помогало запускать проект в `Release` режиме (на панели выпадающим списком). По дефолту там `Debug` стоит.

Comment: сверху фрагмент кода файла cat.cpp,фрагмент кода снизу это заголовочный файл сat.h:#pragma endregion
 private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
  int number = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
  int factor = cat(number);
  textBox2->Text = System::Convert::ToString(factor);
 }

Comment: я хотел запрограммировать кнопку Button для вычисления 1*2 + 2*3*4 и так далее ,я уже задавал вопрос и думал,что предложенное правильное решение для консольного приложения подойдёт и для winforms

Comment: @Noob_Prog код у вас нормальный, дело в самом компиляторе. Перед вторым `if` стоит добавить `else`, а то получается что у вас выполняется и первое условие и третье одновременно